# Parent <> child tree structure with unique child id's by means of recursive SQL query

Tags: sql, tree, telerik, unique, recursive-query

I have data like this:

1. Parent name | Child name
2. parent_A    |child_1
3. parent_A    |child_2
4. parent_B    |child_1

the data is intended to be displayed in Telerik self-referencing hierarchy datagridview component which requires each parent <> child combination is unique. notice child_1 is child of parents parent_A and parent_B (my example is very simplified, just for presentation, real ones consists of many levels and leafs)
.
Then the result needs to be as follow:

1. Parent name | Child name |Child unique ID
2. parent_A    |child_1     |1
3. parent_A    |child_2     |2
4. parent_B    |child_1     |3

Is there a way to achieve this with a recursive query?

I tried to achieve the result with interface procedure but it takes too long to use it.

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: so do you have 2 tables here i.e. parent and child, if so how do you link back the parent record to the children? surely you need a parentID in parent as PK and ParentID as a foreign key in children. You really need to normalise the data.

Comment: I only have one table with Parent and child columns (also some description columns). There is no way to optimize anything as the table is a part of third party system. I can only read data from there.

Comment: can you provide a table schema, or some sample sanitised data so we could comment further?

Comment: how is the child ID currently defined in this structure?

Comment: Child ID is an integer and it repeats in different parents which makes self hierarchy grid impossible to display. Thanks for your interest of the problem.

Comment: yes but an integer based on what? some kind of sequencing I suppose, but unless the ID of the child is separately defined, then the ID is not unique, its just a sequence based on how many children are associated with a parent. - This system should surely feed and take data from a database? is this SQL server? if so can you access it, there maybe some audit information that you could use to create a separate entity of child using a combination of fields, i.e. name, dob, datetime added etc which you could then create a definite unique ID for each child.

Comment: Here is an example of creation of  data for the Telerik rad grid view:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/hierarchical-grid/self-referencing-hierarchy

Child ID (currently) is a part number ID. As one part number may exist in many assemblies, it repeats.

Comment: Imagine, a parent is ID 1, it has child 2, child 2 has child 3 which means child 2 exists in parent table with ID 2 and child 3 exists in child column with ID 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but I am trying to illustrate the problem, and the way you need the data structured to achieve what you are after:

[image]